# Chrome extension problem with change textarea content

Tags: javascript, html

I want to put some content in a textarea. But in a read-only local .mhtml file, I can only use id, class, querySelector, xpath for selection.

When I run the plugin on a real site, select element it is always null...

Czego mam użyć abym mógł zmienić zawartość na stronie ? (Yep I trying with selenium)

```js
document.querySelector('body > div.main-container > div.inner-container > div.page-content > div.col-md-10 > div.profile-container.col-md-6 > div:nth-child(4) > textarea').innerHTML = "content";
```

Comment: why you are using this complicated selector? you can give the textarea any class and then select this class.

Comment: This is not my site

Comment: Are you saying you can't use `getElementsByTagName`? for example with `document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].value = "test";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].value = "content";
```

the [0] indicates it's the first textarea block in the page.  Or find the `id` attribute of the `<textarea>` and use:

```
document.querySelector('#wmd-input').value = 'content';
```

Both of the above will update the contents of the stackoverflow `textarea` in which I'm writing this answer.